# I got an index: 10; from terminal of vscode

Tags: javascript, terminal, visual-studio-code

I was studying regex in javascript. My IDE is VSCODE and suddenly I got a reply from terminal

> [ 'xyz', index: 10, input: 'this is a xyz test' ]

what i did was `console.log(value.match(pattern));` and my other code was

```
let pattern = /xyz/;
let value = 'this is a xyz test';
```

I want to know what does `index : 10` means in the `console` given by VSCODE? I don't even have an idea what to search for.

Comment: start counting.... and read the docs

Comment: Looking at what [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) does sounds like a good idea, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

If the regular expression does not include the g flag, str.match() will return the same result as RegExp.exec(). The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the original string that was parsed. **In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string**.